# Show path on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, gps

I have several GPS coordinates and want to show them on the map connected with line. It must looks like [this](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=480x480&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397&sensor=true).

How can I open maps.google.com page and show this path?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use openlayers.The following link is the example how to draw a line in the map.Once read the openlayers documentation and see the examples. you will get the best solution for your problem.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol.html

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options. Here are a couple of choices:

- you can use [My Maps](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=21670&topic=21676&from=21676&rd=2) to draw the line on maps.google.com - here's a [bike ride I did in Monterey](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=216230369210766641860.00049a619c2ef9b7e41be&z=13) with all sorts of polyline goodness
- you can upload a KML file to a webserver, pasting the url into the search box [like this example](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example3.kml)

Answer (score -3):

Try with SAS.Planet software. It can read a lot of online maps and KML files as well.